# Smartcard Reader and ChromeApp

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, smartcard-reader, winusb

I want to make a Chrome App that can access a USB SmartCard Reader (HID Global OmniKey 3121).

Did someone ever succeed in doing that?

Unfortunately, I cannot see it using `usb.getDevices`.

**script.js** (called by **index.html** which is itself called by **background.js** `onLaunched`):

```
//dom elements
var findBtn = document.querySelector( "button#find-btn" )
var deviceInfo = document.querySelector( "p#device-info" )

//{click}
findBtn.addEventListener( "click", findDevice )

/*
 * Try to find HID OmniKey 3x21
 */
function findDevice ()
{
  var options = {
    filters: [
      {
        vendorId: 1899,  //OmniKey AG
        productId: 12321  //CardMan 3121 but PID=0x3021
      }
    ]
  }

  chrome.usb.getDevices( options, function ( devices )
  {
    console.log( devices )
    deviceInfo.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( devices[0] )
  } )

}
```

The device is declared in the manifest and recognized by Chrome in the Extensions page.

Thank you by advance for your help.

EDIT

Here is my **manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Card Reader",
  "description": "Smartcard reader",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "43",

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "js/background.js" ]
    }
  },

  "permissions": [
    "usb",

    {
      "usbDevices": [
        {
          "vendorId": 1057,
          "productId": 1633
        },
        {
          "vendorId": 1133,
          "productId": 49271
        },
        {
          "vendorId": 1899,
          "productId": 12321
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The 3 permitted devices are:

1. Nokia Lumia 920
2. Dell Optical Mouse
3. OmniKey Smartcard Reader 3121

Only the mouse is recognized by `usb.getDevices` or `usb.findDevices`.
Only the mouse is listed by `usb.getUserSelectedDevices`.

Comment: See [this crbug issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=480994). Also add `manifest.json` (or the relevant parts only: permissions, the background page declaration and such) and the file name of that code fragment.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you again for the link. It led me to http://zadig.akeo.ie/ alternative USB drivers, that are recognized by `chrome.usb` API. Now it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The device is not recognized by Chrome when the native driver from HID Global is used.

The workaround is to **use an alternate USB driver**, for example one provided by the Zadig installer from [zadig.akeo.ie](http://%20zadig.akeo.ie):

- WinUSB
- libusb-win32
- libusbK

---

I opened a case at HID Device but their technical support has not understood the problem yet (they don't know what is the Chrome Platform...) and redirected me to Google.

I opened a case at Google but they answered me I should post on StackOverflow!! They don't seem to mind if their Platform cannot recognize standard USB SmartCard devices, though visible in the Windows device manager...

**Update**

HID technical support said their driver will support the platform by 2016.
Goolge support is still... inapt.

**Update for Windows 7-10**

On Windows 7 and 10 I don't need to install a generic driver. Instead I just edit the Smartcard Reader in *Windows Device Manager* and select the *Previous Driver*. It will revert to the Windows Generic USB CCID driver, that works with both my legacy PC/SC Winscard application and my Chrome App.