# How to get data from smartcard using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, smartcard

I want to develop a simple Chrome-extension that will handle the communication with my smartcard.
After installing a driver (as described at [Smartcard Reader and ChromeApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737190/) ) I can get some information of my device, like this:

```
device #0: {
    "device":0,
    "manufacturerName":"OMNIKEY AG",
    "productId":12322,
    "productName":"Smart Card Reader USB",
    "serialNumber":"",
    "vendorId":1899,
    "version":516
}
```

How can I continue?
I need now to get ATR, and send/get data, and I have no idea how to do it...
(we did it using some program languages, like Java, Python, C++, but I don't know where is the relevant API for JS/chrome)

Comment: The chrome.usb API is available from a Chrome App, not from a Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use the bare chrome.usb API for writing your extension.
Basically, you would have to write a driver for smart card readers according to CCID specification ([here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/DWG_Smart-Card_CCID_Rev110.pdf) is the link to its revision 1.1). This is entirely possible, but is definitely not the easiest task.

The alternative solution would be to utilize the [Smart Card Connector App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smart-card-connector/khpfeaanjngmcnplbdlpegiifgpfgdco) that was recently released by Google. This app already bundles a generic CCID driver and implements more high-level PC/SC API. With this API, such operations as obtaining ATR or sending/receiving data to the card could be performed by relatively simple requests.

P.S. I would like to emphasize the fact that operating with USB devices from Chrome Apps works well and stable only under Chrome OS. With other OSes, there're a lot of possible pitfalls (generally speaking, when something in the system may prevent Chrome from accessing the USB device).